# Can anyone help me identify what set this bag with grey and dark red pieces belongs to?

Tags: set-identification

Can anyone help me identify which Lego set this bag belongs to (it has two smaller bags inside)?

[image]

Comment: I see a "135149" to the right of the bottom "2", is that maybe a set number?

Comment: @Tweakimp - no, that is the part number of the plastic bag itself. The problem with identifying this bag is that the picture quality is quite bad (lots of reflection), and the pieces that are visibly identifiable are very common (as in: appear in thousands of sets)

Comment: Too many generic parts. Having pictures of both sides of polybag might be helpful.

Comment: I don't see any parts sufficiently uncommon to go on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the comments said: it's hard to tell.

But based on

[Plate 2x14 in light buish gray](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=91988&idColor=86#T=C&C=86),

[Slope, Curved 10x1 in light buish gray](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=85970&idColor=86#T=C&C=86) and

[Slope, Curved 3x1 No Studs in  Dark Red](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=50950&idColor=59#T=C&C=59)

i believe it is bag 2 from

**[75012 BARC Speeder with Sidecar](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75012-1#T=I)**
[image]

Comment: Glad I could help. Please feel free to mark this answer as correct by clicking on the little tick-icon on the left side.